# Godot - set_fixed_process function

Tags: game-engine, godot, gdscript

I am trying to understand Godot Game engine, I am following a tutorial, and I wrote a breakout game.
Here is the padding code:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

func _ready():
    set_fixed_process(true)

func _fixed_process(delta):
    var y = get_pos().y
    var x = get_viewport().get_mouse_pos().x
    set_pos(Vector2(x,y))
```

And I don't understand why I can't use the `_fixed_process` function without the `set_fixed_process` function, and what is it's use. What does the function do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **_fixed_process()** function is a callback that is enabled by calling **set_fixed_process(true)**. This is just like how **_process()** isn't called unless you enabled the callback with **set_process()**.

Both functions are essentially telling Godot that you want to receive those callbacks in your script when the nodes are processed. And then you're just overriding the _fixed_process() function to capture it in your script.